# The display of "Markdown Help" is broken on the international sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, international-sites

In SOja's "[Markdown Help](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)", the example display is broken.
This problem seems to occur on other international sites as well.

[Bug report on SO.ja meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3349)

---

**On SOja:** https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

[image]

**On SOru:** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

[image]

**On SO:** https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

[image]

Comment: So es looks ok, at least is in 2 rows... but the second ones is totally indented... is that ok? https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @gbianchi I think the version on SO ES is even better than the version on SO because it is more readable.

Comment: @AdamLear Why was this deferred?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog The bug is on our backlog but there's a number of things ahead of it, so it's not being addressed yet and there's no ETA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have sent in localization changes for each of these pages! The localized string included a newline character, so it was easy to miss during translation.

Here's where each page is currently at:

| Site | Status |
| --- | --- |
| [SOja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) | Fixed, translation fix approved |
| [SOru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) | Pending, translation fix sent, awaiting approval |
| [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) | Pending, translation fix sent, awaiting approval |
| [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) | Fixed, translation was already correct |

Definitely let us know if you see anything else localized strangely on those pages. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Most have been fixed, but one issue remains. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDnH.png

Comment: Thanks for catching that @cubick! I've sent one more translation in with the fixed formatting, it's just waiting on approval.

Comment: All issues have been fixed. Thank you! - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KiRP.png